# Should I Leave a Comment to Eager Editors When Reviewing Suggested Edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I recently was reviewing suggested edits and came across one proposed edit to a self-answer that was placed 3 minutes after the answer was posted. The edit was reasonable, so I approved it. But, should I leave a comment directed at the editor in this situation, suggesting that more time be given to the poster to edit their own answer?

Comment: Why should they wait?

Comment: The 5-minute grace period is more of an escape hatch, not an absolute right. You are *supposed* to post a fully-formed answer the first time around. You're right that lots of people abuse this feature, so much so that we even have a name for it: FGITW. And there are certainly advantages to doing so, for all parties. But one of the side effects is that you might be caught out with an incomplete answer that attracts downvotes and/or edits. In fact, it might be worth pointing out that if I leave a comment within your 5-minute grace period, it ends the grace period and tracks subsequent edits.